# Trying to reach actual child parent on Firebase with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to reach the parent key of a child on Firebase, and also I'm trying to reach the actual key to delete the comment.

As far you can see I'm a newbie, I've searched for two days and read the official documentation of Firebase and React, but no clue about it.

---

This is my data structure on Firebase:

```
|_posts
   |__-LACYTq8c0vi-sRS7MeR <---------- This is the key that I get when I run my function...
   |__-LACYU_Pnry4ncinnzmr <---------- I want to reach this key to update my "count" value.
       |__archived: "unarchived"
       |__author: "User"
       |__body: "<p>asdasdasd</p>"
       |__comments
       |  |__-LACYV6yZlVze8wgkzK0 <--- Also, I want to delete the actual child key.
       |      |__author: "User"
       |      |__commentBody: "asdasdasd"
       |      |__date: "2018-04-16T10:24:18+02:00"
       |      |__profpic: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tltWG_wU87s/..."
       |      |__uid: "oIThCjDLsOgv1EYmzKZrBuy31Qn1"
       |__count: 3 <------------------ I want to update this value.
       |__date: "2018-04-16T10:24:16+02:00"
       |__title: "Test 01"
       |__uid:"oIThCjDLsOgv1EYmzKZrBuy31Qn1"
```

And this is my actual code to try to reach the parent key and remove it:

```
    export function deleteComment(key, postId) {
    return dispatch => {
        database.ref().child('posts').once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                var key = child.ref.key;
                //database.child(key).remove();
                console.log(key);
                return deleteComment;
            })
        });
    }
   }
```

With this function I only get this key:

> -LACYTq8c0vi-sRS7MeR

When I want to reach this:

> -LACYU_Pnry4ncinnzmr

This is the actual code that triggers the function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SubmitComment from './SubmitComment';
import { deleteComment } from '../../actions/commentActions';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Comment from './Comment';
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
import FlipMove from 'react-flip-move';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';

class PostDetail extends Component {
    renderComments() {
        const { posts } = this.props;
        return _.map(posts.comments, (comment, key ) => {
            return (
              <div key={key} id={key}>
                <Comment>
                    <div className="col-md-12 comments">
                      <div className="btn-group pull-right postbtn">
                        <button type="button" className="dotbtn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span className="dots"></span> </button>
                        { this.props.user === null ? (
                          <div>
                          </div>
                        ) : ( comment.uid === this.props.user.uid &&
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
                          <li>
                            <button className="btn btn-default no-border postbuttons" onClick={() => this.props.deleteComment(key)}>
                              <p>Delete</p>
                            </button>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      )}
                      </div>
                      <div className="media">
                        <div className="media-left">
                           <a href=""> <img src={comment.profpic} alt="" className="media-object"></img></a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="media-body">
                          <h4 className="media-heading">{comment.author}</h4>
                            <small><em><Moment fromNow locale="es">{comment.date}</Moment></em></small><br/><br/>
                          <p>{comment.commentBody}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </Comment>
              </div>
            );
        }).reverse();
    }

    render() {
        const { posts } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <h1>{posts.title}</h1>
                        {renderHTML(posts.body)}
                        { posts.lastedit === null ? (
                        <div>
                        </div>
                      ) : ( posts.lastedit >= 0 &&
                        <div className="">
                          <small><em><p>Last edit: </p><Moment fromNow locale="es">{posts.lastedit}</Moment></em></small>
                        </div>
                        )}
                        {this.props.user === null ? (
                          <div>
                            {this.renderComments()}
                          <br />
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          <div>
                            <SubmitComment id={this.props.match.params.id} />
                            <div>
                              <FlipMove
                staggerDurationBy="150"
                duration={500}
                enterAnimation={"fade"}
                leaveAnimation={"fade"}
                appearAnimation={"fade"}
                >
                                {this.renderComments()}
                              </FlipMove>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )}

                        <Link to="/"> &#171; Back</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        posts: state.posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
        user: state.user
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteComment })(PostDetail);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach the second child, you can just count the nodes in your `forEach()`:

```
database.ref().child('posts').once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var i = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == 2) {
            var key = child.key;
            console.log(key);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer, but I think that I'ven't explained quite well, I don't want to reach the second child, I want to reach the parent key of each child key. Actually my content is dynamic, so when I click on the delete option on my system, I want that the function reachs his parent key to update the count and also remove the actual comment key....

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing with

```
database.ref().child('posts').once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
```

is to loop over all the children of the 'posts' node.

If you already know the keys of the child (and grand-child) you want to change, what you need to do is to update the exact children you are targetting.

Read this part of the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Based on this doc you could do something like:

```
var updates = {};
updates['/posts/-LACYU_Pnry4ncinnzmr/count'] = 4;   e.g. you update from 3 to 4
updates['/posts/-LACYU_Pnry4ncinnzmr/comments/-LACYV6yZlVze8wgkzK0'] = null;
return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: I've tried to get the key as the documentation says, but I only get "posts" as a result, not the actual parent key of the triggered child.

I've updated my OP with the code that triggers the function. Thanks!

Comment: @sergimm What is exactly the triggered child? Is it the comment with ID -LACYV6yZlVze8wgkzK0 ? Which Id do you have in your front-end? How did you get it?

Comment: Yes, is the -LACYV6yZlVze8wgkzK0, I've pasted the code on the OP that triggers the function, I hope it helps.

Comment: @sergimm I see your update but to be frank I am not qualified in React (I use Vue.js :-)) but with the logic of what you are trying to do we should find an answer. If you have the child id, you should denormalized your data in such a way that from your child Id you get the parent id and then do what I have explained in my answer. Denormalizing meaning to have another node in the db where for each child id you save the parent id (when the child is created). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been thinking about denormalizing my db to avoid this kind of problems, but I readed about Firebase and his advanced query introduced on 2015 and I wanted to see if I can go deeper with this workaround....

Comment: Frank van Puffelen may confirm or refute, but I don't think that you can, from a child node Id, directly find back the parent node id.

Comment: @sergimm Did you finally find a solution or decide for a specific approach?

Comment: I’m trying to denormalize my db actually. I’ll update the OP when I find a solution. Thx :)